# I wonder if pinned Data Tip is really shows realtime values while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

While playing around with vars watching while debugging by means of Watch Table (below at both pictures) and Data Tips (at code field), I've faced with an odd thing as follows:

I can't get realtime variable watching. The first picture while debugging with breakpoint and second one with no any breakpoints. Both show **i=1**. In fact a value of <**i**> is much more than 1 and runs up, though. And I obtain always static values. I'm not sure if VS2015 provides such function as *real time var watching*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the interval of your timer? Does the value of `textBox1.Text` changes?

Comment: The code itself is working fine. As I wrote above var <i> value runs up with set timer interval 250ms. The code itself is not an issue. Watching on variable is not plausible, that's an issue! Normally at watch Table and at Data Tip var <i> value should be running up too.

Comment: Try putting in a tracepoint (breakpoint with an action of automatically continuing).  The debugger needs to hit a breakpoint, however briefly, to reevaluate its watch expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally found that if press twice or more times the "Continue" button while Debugging, this refreshes values. But this no that I expected from VS2015 variable watching option.